# issues importing .tsv to sql Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am trying to simply import a .tsv (200 column, 400,000 rows) to Sql Server.

I get this error all the time (always with a different column):

Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 93" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

Even though I explicitly:
[image]

So, I found myself, going back, and changing the Output (500 for this case):
[image]

Is there a way to change all OutputColumnWidth to like ‘max’ at once?! I have 200 columns I can't wait for it to fail and go back and change it for each failed column... (I do not care about performance, any data type is the same for me)

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening the code view of your SSIS package and doing a ctrl-H replace of all "50" to "500".  If you have 50's you don't want to change to 500 then look at the code and make the replacement more context-specific.